# Change feature hover cursor in Openlayers 2

Tags: openlayers

How to change the cursor on hover feature in openlayers 2? It is "move" by default.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can listen for pointermove and change the style, based on the feature below the cursor
:

```
map.on('pointermove', (evt) => {
  if (evt.dragging) {
    // the event is a drag gesture, this is handled by openlayers (map move)
    return;
  }
  const pixel = this.map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
  const feature = this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
    pixel,
    someFeature => someFeature // returns first element,
    {
        // optional: only look at specific layers
        layerFilter: function(layer) { return true; }
    }
  );

  // change the cursor style
  this.map.getTarget().style.cursor = feature ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```